# React Native build does not send request to http server

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, axios

When I build my application in .apk and test the application on my phone, when I send a request, I get an `AxiosError: Network Error`

Hi all! I use Expo in my development. When sending requests, I first used `fetch`, now I use `axios` (I thought the problem would be solved this way). During development, everything works: requests are sent to the server, I receive responses from the server, everything is fine and wonderful. When I compile my application in `.apk` and test the application on my phone, when I send a request, I receive the error `AxiosError: Network Error`. This is what a request to the server looks like (for security reasons, I hid the address with the letter `x`):

```
`await axios.post('http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000/api/reg', reg_data, {
    headers: { 
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type,Authorization',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS'
    }
})
    .then(async(response) => {
        result = {id: response.data.id, error: false}
    })
    .catch(async error => {
        result = {id: false, error}
    })`
```

I checked it through `Postman`, everything works too. Server on `express.js`. If there is not enough information, write in the comments, I will show you everything. Help me please.

Comment: Is the IP address used a real public IP address on the web, or is it a local server?  If it's a local server, are you on the same wifi network (not cellular)?  And do you have a hole poked in whatever router/firewall/NAT you use?

Comment: I am using a public ip with http protocol

Comment: http can be a problem.  Nobody should use http anymore.  Use https.  By default, Android cannot load http websites, and the Play Store will not accept an app that uses an http url.

Answer (score 0):

Please add cors to your `express`:

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
```

Comment: I already have it. Does not help :(